# Getting text between special characters using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to get the words between special character '|' which are in format `[a-z]+@[0-9]+`.

Sample text -

```
||ABC@123|abc@123456||||||ABcD@12||
```

Expected output -

```
ABC@123, abc@123456, ABcD@12
```

Regex i'm using

```
(?i)\\|[a-z]+@[0-9]+\\|
```

When I used this regex, the output i'm getting is `|ABC@123|`

What mistake I'm doing ? Can somebody help me with this please ?

Comment: Just use `split()` with "|" .

Comment: @TheLostMind `|` is a special regex character, you need to escape it

Comment: @assylias - I thought about it. but then I thought, he could also use `"[|]"` :P. So, I didn't mention `"\\|"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches but don't include it the match.

```
(?<=\||^)[a-z]+@[0-9]+(?=\||$)
```

Here is [regex101 online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/6)

Sample code:

```
String pattern = "(?i)(?<=\\||^)[a-z]+@[0-9]+(?=\\||$)";
String str = "|ABC@123|abc@123456|ABcD@12";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
ABC@123
abc@123456
ABcD@12
```

---

`Lookahead` and `lookbehind`, collectively called `lookaround`, are zero-length assertions. The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called "assertions".

[Read more...](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \|                       '|'
   |                        OR
    ^                        the beginning of the line
  )                        end of look-behind

  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
  @                        '@'
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)

  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \|                       '|'
   |                        OR
    $                         the end of the line
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the `|` in your pattern, otherwise it will be matched. Use the lookaraound operators as in the other solution, or just match ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/iK2yF2/1)):

```
[a-z]+@\d+
```

You should also consider splitting the string on `|` as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).